# Are news article identification questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question

I have a news article I am really trying to recall. The story being a disgruntled employee modifies all email accounts to pass authentication regardless of the given password.

While this relates to information security, it isn't a direct question regarding best practices - it's story identification. Is this appropriate for this stack or should it remain [on Tip of my Tongue](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/d1uolm/tomtnews_articledisgruntled_employee_makes_every/) where it has already been posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would not be on topic, correct.

Comment: It's unfortunate I won't be able to get more eyes on the question. It is what it is, I suppose